# Probability - why does equiprobability (in $\Omega$) can be extended to the event $B$ when considering that $B$ has happened?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In the Introduction to Probability course of MIT (6.012), we are assuming that twelve equiprobable elementary events are taking place in a universe $\Omega$, as indicated in this Venn diagram: [image]

Professor then says "since the twelve points are equiprobable in $\Omega$, when assuming $B$ has happened, the remaining six points in $B$ must be equiprobable as well".

I don't know much about probability theory (even though I am "reading" Jaynes' book Probability Theory, but I skip a lot in the book) neither do I know about measure theory but I was wondering if there could be an argument that shows equiprobability can be extended to the elements of $B$ (when considering that $B$ has happened) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the term "equiprobable" in my answer below. That term is certainly correct and appropriate, but often, especially in the continuous setting, you'll probably hear "uniform" instead of "equiprobable."

For a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}$ with $\mathbb{P}(B)>0$, the conditional probability of $A\in\mathcal{B}$ given that $B$ has occurred is (by usually by definition) $$\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}\tag{1}$$ So, in the Venn diagram, we're restricting to subsets of $B$ (that is why we have $A\cap B$, so we are only concerned with the part of $A$ that is in $B$) and dividing by $\mathbb{P}$ (so that the conditional probability of $B$ given that $B$ has occurred is $\mathbb{P}(B\cap B)/\mathbb{P}(B)=1$).

For a finite probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$, "equiprobable" means that there exists $p$ such that, if $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ are the members of the probability space, $\mathbb{P}(\{x_i\})=p$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,p$. Then $$1=\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{P}(\{x_i\})=pN,$$ and $p=1/N$. So, in other words, each individual outcome $x_i$ satisfies $\mathbb{P}(\{x_i\})=1/N$. Then if $A\subset \Omega$ is a non-empty subset of $\Omega$ and if $x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_{|A|}}$ are the members of $A$, then $$\mathbb{P}(A)=\sum_{j=1}^{|A|}\mathbb{P}(\{x_{i_j}\})=|A|/N.$$  This is clearly also true if $A=\varnothing$, since $\mathbb{P}(\varnothing)=0=0/N$. So we have $\mathbb{P}(A)=|A|/N=|A|/|\Omega|$ for $A\subset \Omega$ in the case of equiprobability. The converse is also true. That is, if $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$ is a finite probability space with $\mathbb{P}(A)=|A|/|\Omega|$ for all $A\subset \Omega$, then $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$ is an equiprobable space. To see this, we can just take all sets $A$ with $|A|=1$. Now assume $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$ is a finite equiprobable probability space and fix $\varnothing\neq B\subset \Omega$. Then for any $A\subset B$, $$\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}=\frac{|A|/|\Omega|}{|B|/|\Omega}=\frac{|A|}{|B|}.$$ In particular, for $x\in B$, $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}|B)=1/|B|$. This shows that $B$ is equiprobable.

The preceding deals with discrete equiprobable spaces. On the other hand, in the continuous setting, "equiprobable" means that we have a probability density function which is constant **everywhere that it is positive**. That is, suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}$ are such that $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} c & : x\in \Omega \\ 0 & : x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \Omega,\end{array}\right.$$ from which it follows that and $$\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\int_A f(x)dx = \int_{A\cap \Omega} c dx = cm(A),$$ where $m(A)$ is the measure of $A$.  We have $$1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=\int_\Omega c dx = cm(\Omega),$$ so $c=1/m(\Omega)$ (which is directly analogous to $1/N$ in the discrete case). Thus the pdf of a continuous, equiprobable distribution on $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}$ is $f(x)=\frac{1_\Omega}{m(\Omega)}$, where $1_\Omega$ is the indicator of $\Omega$ ($1_\Omega(x)=1$ if $x\in \Omega$ and $1_\Omega(x)=0$ otherwise). So $$\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\int_A \frac{1_\Omega(x)}{m(\Omega)}dx$$ in this case.

For $B\subset \Omega$ and $A\subset B$, $$\mathbb{P}(X\in A|B)=\frac{\int_A f(x)dx}{\int_B f(x)dx} = \frac{m(A)/m(\Omega)}{m(B)/m(\Omega)}=\frac{m(A)}{m(B)}=\int_A \frac{1_B}{m(B)}(x)dx.$$ So the pdf of $\mathbb{P}(\cdot|B)$ is $\frac{1_B}{m(B)}$, which is constant on $B$ and $0$ otherwise. Again, this is the equiprobable distribution on $B$.